# Life of variable in Javascript Closure

Tags: javascript

In below code(Node.js), it prints `1 2`

```
   function count(){
        var counter = 0
        function inc(){
            counter++
            console.log(counter);
        }

        return inc
    }
    var x = count();
    x()
    x()
```

Does that means that variable `counter` being available to `inc()` due to closure will live lifetime of the program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: In short, yes it will be. It'll be available as long as x is available.

Comment: @MikeS. Thanks, may be you could write this as an answer so that I could accept.

Comment: @AndrewL. I wouldn't say it to be a duplicate per say because the question and answer both don' t highlight the life of a variable shared by closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be. It'll be available as long as x is available.

Comment: Well, the question was "will live lifetime of program". The correct answer is actually "No, it'll be available as long as `x` is available`, which is a different thing.